# Condense observable operations into single chain

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a segment of code containing some observable operations which I think should be possible to condense as they share the same end goal. However as I am fairly new to RxJs I can't quite figure out how to do it. Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
    if (isCommerceOrV3) {
                linkObservable$ = this.handleCommerceOrV3Notifications(parsedUrl).pipe(
                        switchMap(isExternalOrGoToSection => {
                            if (isExternalOrGoToSection) {
                                return this.linksManager.handleLink(url, sectionId);
                            }

                            return EMPTY;
                        }
                    ));
                } else {
                    linkObservable$ = this.handleClassicNotifications(parsedUrl).pipe(
                        switchMap(isExternalOrGoToSection => {
                            if (isExternalOrGoToSection) {
                                return this.linksManager.handleLink(url, sectionId);
                            }

                            return EMPTY;
                        }
                    ));
                }
    }
```

Comment: You can use `const  linkObservable$ = isCommerceOrV3 ?this.handleCommerceOrV3Notifications(parsedUrl) : this.handleClassicNotifications(parsedUrl)` and then pipe some operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really is quite a few ways to do this. The following answer is the same as Alexey's, just with some more detail. To me this also seems to be the most elegant solution:

```
const notificationOperation = isCommerceOrV3
  ? this.handleCommerceOrV3Notifications
  : this.handleClassicNotifications;

linkObservable$ = notificationOperation(parsedUrl).pipe(
  switchMap(isExternalOrGoToSection => isExternalOrGoToSection
    ? this.linksManager.handleLink(url, sectionId)
    : EMPTY;
  )
);
```

If it's not clear, in the top part we reference the relevant method to a function variable using a ternary operator on the isCommerceOrV3 boolean(?).

In the next part we invoke the respective method via the `notificationOperation` reference variable and use the common piping sequence.

In the `switchMap` we also use the arrow function shorthand without a code block, returning another ternary statement and the relevant observable.

Comment: All other answers also worked but I think this one is the more readable one and I appreciate the effort you took explaining every step. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

How about [`iif`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/iif) for outer condition and ternary operator for inner observable?

Try the following

```js
linkObservable$ = iif(
  () => isCommerceOrV3,
  this.handleCommerceOrV3Notifications(parsedUrl),
  this.handleClassicNotifications(parsedUrl)
).pipe(
  switchMap((isExternalOrGoToSection: any) => 
    isExternalOrGoToSection
      ? this.linksManager.handleLink(url, sectionId)
      : EMPTY
  )
);
```

Comment: Possibly a tad less readable to a junior, for the sake of keeping a single statement, but otherwise I think I prefer this over my previous answer

Answer (score 1):

```
linkObservable$ = (isCommerceOrV3 ? this.handleCommerceOrV3Notifications(parsedUrl) : this.handleClassicNotifications(parsedUrl)).pipe(...)
```

though it's likely more readable if you extract the ternary into a variable:

```
const someNameThatMakesSenseInContext = isCommerceOrV3 ? this.handleCommerceOrV3Notifications(parsedUrl) : this.handleClassicNotifications(parsedUrl)
linkObservable$ = someNameThatMakesSenseInContext.pipe(...)
```